# PHP to Python3 HMAC signature not resulting in the same signature

Tags: php, python

I have been trying to convert a php script to a `python3` script and have been failing to send through a successful signature after troubleshooting through the issue.

The below `PHP` example code successfully goes through so I've copied the sent timestamp and signature to try and replicate it in my python3 code.

**PHP Code**

```
<?
    $nonce = "2015-10-26 04:53:49 EDT";
    $secret = "mkdaklmdflfkdsmaflkdmsfdkasmfdsmflks";

    $req = array();
    $req['t'] = $nonce;
    $req['secret'] = $secret;

    $post_data = json_encode($req);
    $post_data = bin2hex($post_data);
    $sign = hash_hmac("sha256", $post_data, $secret);

    print($sign);

?>
```

**Python 3 Code**

```
import json
import hmac
import binascii
import hashlib


nonce = "2015-10-26 04:53:49 EDT"
secret = "mkdaklmdflfkdsmaflkdmsfdkasmfdsmflks"

payload = {}
payload["t"] = nonce
payload["secret"] = secret

payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
post_data = binascii.b2a_hex(payload_json.encode('utf-8'))
sign = hmac.new(bytes(secret, "utf-8"), post_data, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(sign)
```

Based on the successful request using PHP my signature should be:

```
'c30ddc5878ff7b1a9b1c9078ccbdc38afef25ed510681a3d3bfc56f6c9e2f26a'
```

Instead I'm getting:

```
'f9fc8749389137252e7f207468d88a5c871110403ec533496720efd715541ec2'
```

Any help troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to `Python`.

Comment: Please post some dummy data that we can use to reproduce this issue?

Comment: It's most probably due to unicode data, PHP's hmac function works fine with unicode data and on the other hand Python's hmac function only works with bytes.

Comment: You can convert `postdata` to a similar form using bin-2-hex functions in both Python and PHP. Python 3: `binascii.b2a_hex(postdata.encode('utf-8'))` PHP: `bin2hex(postdata);`

Comment: You should be able to put in any data as long at the secret and time are the same we should get the same signature on php and python, in order for the authentication to be successful from my understanding.

I've tried using the above code and have got the following result

'8c79bb3f7a5db920b601a6b9643b212f26451d2b0d7e79f2fd04a476f03e2f68'

I didn't think it was the datatype error as I have converted the str to bytes prior to the signature using.

`bytes(payload_json, 'utf-8')`

Thanks for your help so far... I've been stumped on this one

Comment: Here is the api docs for the request which I'm trying to send http://docs.cointrader.apiary.io/

Comment: In Python you did convert the data, but the same thing is not applicable to PHP. The code will work fine with ASCII data, but will return different signatures for unicode data. Try to convert `postdata` to a similar form before passing it to the corresponding hmac function, you can use functions like `bin2hex`, `base64`, etc for that.

Comment: Gotcha... sorry I misunderstood. After converting my $post_data variable using `bin2hex($post_data);` my authentication is successful with PHP but still not showing the same signature as in Python.
**Python** signature = '572bae5957be70eb06750c1e80d88cd9b1a4f2648fee935f771cd052b5435714'
**PHP** signature = '5add3d19d8f0c718062459c5a9ad0eb35eaab7db5231e8793863d53bf14084ca'

Comment: Are you using the same function in Python as well? in Python use binascii.b2a_hex.

Comment: Yep, thats the result from using it in PHP and Python. My reasoning for comparing the signatures is to troubleshoot the formatting of my python request. I should get the same match using your suggestion?

Comment: Please post your your current code as well as some dummy data that results in different signatures in the question body.

Comment: Just updated the above question with example code which can be easily run.

Comment: You're not assigning `bin2hex($post_data);` anywhere?

Comment: The line just before I sign the data

Comment: That's not an assignment, you're calling a function and not doing anything with the returned value.

Comment: From my understanding that function is built into PHP. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_bin2hex.asp

Comment: What difference does that make? Use `$post_data = bin2hex($post_data);`.

Comment: signature becomes: 'c30ddc5878ff7b1a9b1c9078ccbdc38afef25ed510681a3d3bfc56f6c9e2f26a' for the PHP code

Comment: Now compare the values of json strings in both PHP and Python, note that Python dicts don't have any order, so you will end up with mismatched data. I would recommend sorting the data is some particular order and then joining the values using `|` operator.

Comment: PHP: http://ideone.com/azfS4G, Python: http://ideone.com/EUIAed Using case-insensitive key sorting. For older PHP versions(5.4.0 or older) you will have to use `uksort($req, 'strcasecmp');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that by default, Python inserts spaces into the JSON string. Output of the PHP json_encode($req):

```
{"t":"2015-10-26 04:53:49 EDT","secret":"mkdaklmdflfkdsmaflkdmsfdkasmfdsmflks"}
```

Output of the Python json.dumps(payload):

```
{"t": "2015-10-26 04:53:49 EDT", "secret": "mkdaklmdflfkdsmaflkdmsfdkasmfdsmflks"}
```

You can fix this by specifying separators, i.e.:

```
json.dumps(payload, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Also, you can control the order of the elements by using OrderedDict instead of a plain dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

payload = OrderedDict()
```